# Trigger a child click event when clicking on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

Say you have this html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="child"></a>
    <span>other elements</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="child"></a>
    <span>other elements</span> 
</div>
```

the child have a click event listener:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.child', doSomething );
```

How can I make the click be triggered if any part of the parent element is clicked?
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. The doSomething function isn't getting triggered.

```
$('.parent').each( function() {
    $(this).on( 'click', function( e ){
        $(this).find('.child').triggerHandler('click');
        e.preventDefault();
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `.each()` at all here.

You can try the following way:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('.child').get(0).click();
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('body').on('click', '.child', doSomething);

function doSomething(e){
  console.log('Child of ' +$(e.target).parent().index() +' parent tiggered');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="child"></a>
    <span>other elements</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="child"></a>
    <span>other elements</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle a click for `.parent` elements, then why not simply attach an event handler to `.parent`?

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.parent', doSomething);
```

Also according to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance)

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance [...] 
> For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location
> as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of
> document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.

```
// For example, instead of 
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment )
// use 
$( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment ).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.parent, .child', function (event) {
   // do something

});
```